# Statistics for Galois groups of polynomials of bounded height

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-groups

Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^ma_ix^i$ be a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, and let $H(f)=\max_i\{|a_i|\}$. Moreover, let $\text{Gal}(f)$ denote the Galois group of $f$.

Now, for every positive integer $N$, let $A(m,N)=\{f\in \mathbb Z[x]\colon \deg f=m, H(f)\leq N, \text{Gal}(f)\simeq S_n\}$. It is a well-known fact that, for every fixed $m$, one has that
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{|A(m,N)|}{(2N+1)^m}=1,$$
in fact we even know accurate bounds on the error term.

My question is: what happens if we fix $N$ and let $m\to \infty$? Is it true again that $\displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{|A(m,N)|}{(2N+1)^m}=1$? And if the answer is yes, what is it known about the error term?